# How to manage java threads running on webserver?

Tags: tomcat, web-applications, webserver, weblogic

I'm running a web application that runs a java code, the java code add it's own threads. What is the recommended way to manage those threads.
Right now the thread are not managed and when the webapp stopped running on the webserver the java thread continues in the backround

Comment: In addition to the answer below, make sure you add `destroy()` methods where needed.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `ServletContextListener` and stop the background tasks when the [context is destroyed](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html#contextDestroyed%28javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent%29).